# multiple input radio inside multiple ng-repeat doesn't get checked with ng-checked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-checked

I'm creating a table where each cell will have multiple radio buttons.

See screenshot:

[image]

I'm creating the options dynamically and I want to check the radio button for each cell based on data that I have before hand.

What I'm doing is to ask for every radio the current value for the group of radiobuttons

```
<li ng-repeat="value in vm.values">
  <input ng-checked="vm.getAnswer(one, two, value.value)" type="radio" ng-value="{{value.value}}" name="radio-{{one}}-{{two}}"> {{value.label}}
</li>
```

But only the option on the last cell is being checked, the first one is unchecked even when in the html says `checked=checked` on the right input.

I've created a plnkr with a demo with the same problem I have.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0QF1ihd6NQsqAM6LMxK0?p=preview

Comment: I ended up doing another approach. Here's an updated Plnkr with the problem solved http://plnkr.co/edit/VqPdceqIKTl58BwbdcKS?p=preview